# Complex jQuery if statements including operators

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement

I would like to show a different **div** depending on what class my 3 **span** elems contain.
If all **span** hasClass *up* or *up1* the code would show a **div** with class *allUp* . If it hasClass *up* *up1* and *down* then it would show a **div** with class *twoUp*.

I wrote the following, but of course it doesn't work.

```
var $line1 = $(".line1")
var $line2 = $(".line2")
var $line3 = $(".line3")

if($line1.hasClass("up") || $line1.hasClass("up1")
&& $line2.hasClass("up") || $line2.hasClass("up1")
&& $line3.hasClass("up") || $line3.hasClass("up1")) {
    $(".allUp").show();
} 
else if ($line1.hasClass("up") || $line1.hasClass("up1")
&& $line2.hasClass("up") || $line2.hasClass("up1")
&& $line3.hasClass("down") || $line3.hasClass("down1")) {
    $(".twoUp").show();
}
else if ($line1.hasClass("up") || $line1.hasClass("up1")
&& $line2.hasClass("down") || $line2.hasClass("down1")
&& $line3.hasClass("down") || $line3.hasClass("down1")) {
    $(".oneUp").show();
}
else {
    $(".down").show();
}
```

***think I've fixed the syntax errors***

Comment: `elseif` ? Use `else if` in JavaScript.

Comment: `$("line1")` this is not a valid variable name in javascript

Comment: Make a jsfiddle plz!

Comment: @FaizAhmed There's no need for a fiddle, OP should fix the syntax errors first.

Comment: Always keep your browser's developer console open while testing out your code.

Comment: I don't know if this question should be answered or closed but if it should be answered then @Pointy's comment is probably at least half the answer. Maybe the other half would be that you can't write a script just by writing a bunch of random lines of code you don't understand and hope it will somehow work.

Comment: okay you're right this is a horrible attempt at it! I've fixed syntax errors and here's a codepen... http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Gqzgt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work, and tidies your logic up quite a lot. I've also updated it with your class-names for lines 1, 2 and 3.

```
var $lines = $('.line1, .line2, .line3'),
    numUp = $lines.filter('.up, .up1').length,
    classes = [ 'allDown', 'oneUp', 'twoUp', 'allUp' ];

$( '.' + classes[numUp] ).show();
```

Comment: thanks for this - happy to have got the correct layout and logic. however it still [doesn't run](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Gqzgt)

Comment: Updated - my logic was back to front (checking 3, 2, 1 instead of 1, 2, 3). Also, here's a working CodePen http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qcGpo

Comment: this works but does not take into account .down1 and .down - also gives allDown when line1 is up and line3 is up

Comment: Ah, I see. In that case, one moment - easy fix :)

Comment: @user3246460 OK, updated (CodePen updated too)

Comment: this works better, but still is unable to account for the numbered suffix... thank you for your help so far!

Comment: What do you mean by the numbered suffix that it doesn't handle?

Comment: in the codepen the spans have classes up, down, up1 but the resulting div has the class oneUp

Comment: I don't understand what you're aiming for. It counts the `.up` and `.up1` then shows `.oneUp`, `.twoUp` etc for the corresponding number. That's what your original code does as well. What do you actually want to do?

Comment: the class up1 should count as just up, so (up,up,up1) is allUp (up,up1,down) is twoUp etc

Comment: Ah - that was a typo stopped it doing that, I thought it already did :) Updated post and CodePen

Comment: thanks it's all working now! would you mind giving a quick explanation as to how it works?

Answer (score 0):

the `var $('line') = line` should be `var line = $('line')`, and `elseif` should be `else if`

Comment: This is just for starters... the selectors are invalid too: line1, line2 and line3 are not elements :).